# RecyclerView Adapter onBindViewHolder never called unless I turn the screen off and on

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

My adapter works fine, it shows all the items I have given to it using a list etc. The only problem is that the items are never shown unless I turn the device screen on and off! Only then is the method onBindViewHolder called.

The code I use to create&set the adapter. It is ran from a different thread using the EventBus library hence runOnUiThread

```
@Subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(EchoListEvent event){

    final EchoListEvent eventt = event;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final EchoListAdapter adapter = new EchoListAdapter(eventt.getList(), R.layout.location_item);
            final RecyclerView listview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            listview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        }
    });

}
```

from resource .xml the RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I've also tried forcing the onBindViewHolder call using Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged but nothing happens.

Comment: Is your `run()` function getting called when you expect it to?  Put a log entry in there and see if it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Basically, the list I was passing to the event was getting populated by an callback which ran an in yet another thread. The API that the callback uses is kind of slow, so the list only got populated after the event had already been posted. The solution was to wait for the callback to finish before posting the event

TL;DR: threading is hard

Comment: I think you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the callback.